# How to change the background color when checked

Tags: css, bulma

So there's plenty of answers on how to traditionally do this but I'm using a CSS library, Bulma, and none of those solutions seem to work. I need to just simply be able to change the color of the checkbox when checked.

I've tried using !important to make it work but doesn't change.

```
<div >
 <label class="checkboxes" for="exact" id="color">
 <input type="checkbox" id="exact" value="exact" checked>
  Exact
 </label>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle with the css library added.
https://jsfiddle.net/yqwp4eoh/

Comment: Where is the javascript that is supposed to change the color?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp Look here on how to create custom checkboxes just using standard css and html.

Answer (score 1):

**You cannot change the default checkbox background**. You have to hide it and make a custom one, either set its `width/height` to `0`, or set `display: none` to hide it, then use a `span` or the `:before/:after` pseudo-classes to apply your styles.

Here is a detailed example from [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_custom_checkbox.asp):

```css
/* The container */
.container {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 35px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 22px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

/* Hide the browser's default checkbox */
.container input {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}

/* Create a custom checkbox */
.checkmark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  background-color: #eee;
}

/* On mouse-over, add a grey background color */
.container:hover input ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

/* When the checkbox is checked, add a blue background */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

/* Create the checkmark/indicator (hidden when not checked) */
.checkmark:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}

/* Show the checkmark when checked */
.container input:checked ~ .checkmark:after {
  display: block;
}

/* Style the checkmark/indicator */
.container .checkmark:after {
  left: 9px;
  top: 5px;
  width: 5px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid white;
  border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="container">Exact
    <input type="checkbox" value="exact" checked="checked">
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
  </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either use `accent-color: red;` in the css file for the checkbox id or class whatever you like.
for example you can use:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1"value="Bike">
```

My vehicle

for css you can use:

```
<style>
#vehicle1{
accent-color: red;
</style>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).